# Ruby/Rails: Best way to loop through a csv and set flag when new person is found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I feel like this is programming 101 stuff, but I am going to swallow my pride and ask for help. I have a CSV that I am processing. Here is a sample...

```
person_id, name, start_date
1111, busta, 1/1/14
1111, busta, 1/4/14
1111, busta, 1/7/14
2222, mista, 1/3/14
2222, mista, 1/1/14
2222, mista, 1/11/14
```

...and here is a sample of the code I am using to process the rows...

```
def self.import(file)
  student_start_dates = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }

CSV.foreach(file.tempfile, :headers => true) do |row|
  student_start_dates[row["person_id"]] << row["start_date"]
  #need something in the loop that says hey...when I find a new person_id send this array to the process method
  end
end

  def self.process(student)
    #process something like 1111 => ["1/1/14", "1/4/14", "1/7/14"]
  end
```

So as you can see from the data each student has multiple start dates associated with them. I am trying to build an array of start_dates for each student. When I find a new person_id, then need to 'do some stuff' with my start_date array. My question is what is the best way to add logic that looks for a change in the person_id as I loop through each row in my csv? I know I could set some sort of flag that gets set when the person_id changes, then based on the state of that flag process my start_date array, and reset the flag. However, I'm tried implementing that without much luck. Or when it did it felt 'dirty'. Just hoping a fresh set of eyes will give me some ideas on cleaner code.

A big part of my issue is the best way to set a flag that says "..when you find a new student (new person_id) then call the process method to find the earliest start date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you're trying to get a resulting hash that would look something like {1111 => ["1/1/14", "1/4/14", "1/7/14"], 2222 => [...], ...}

If so you could use the built in CSV parser and just construct the hash as you loop over each row.

```
# Create the hash, the default value will be an array
student_start_dates = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }

CSV.foreach(file_name, :headers => true) do |row|
  student_start_dates[row["person_id"]] << row["start_date"]
end
```

Comment: I think you meant `student_start_dates[row["person_id"]] << row["start_date"]`

Comment: I made some edits to my question and tried to make my goal more clear. Rather than process the entire csv and create a huge nested array I am hoping to only process a single student at a time. So essential once I get 1111 => ["1/1/14", "1/4/14", "1/7/14"], then I send that to my 'process' method to do some parsing (find earliest start_date), and I would write this to the DB, then more on to the next set of rows (next student).

Comment: It's probably a lot safer (and cleaner) to process the file in one go and then do whatever with the resulting data.  I say this because it's best practice to not assume any order on the data in the csv file.

Once the student_start_dates hash is created you can loop over that to send to your process function.  For example, `student_start_dates.each { |id, dates| Student.process(id, dates) }`